# Stop the Unix `tar` command from creating a full directory path on unpacking

Tags: macos, bash, archive, tar

### Background

I use the `tar` command on Mac OS X often, primarily because I rely heavily of `find` and "*LaunchBar*".

*LaunchBar* is an application launcher invoked by a keyboard command. Press command-space ( *configurable* ) and a small window pops up. Start typing the first few characters of an *app*, *file*, *command*, *shell script*, *AppleScript*, etc., press return, and the command is invoked.

*LaunchBar* creates an index of all your files for lightning fast access to your entire file system plus some other application specific niceties, eg: *move files*, *copy files*, *resize files*, *play songs*, *skip songs*, *add reminders/notes*, *google search*, *tight integration with the entire OS*, *append text*, and amusingly enough, you can create `.tgz` file(s) .

When I'm done with a project I no longer want it in my index — I can open the index and exclude that project from showing up in *LaunchBar*, which works, but *LaunchBar* tries hard to hide itself and it's application bundle (*.app* ) and even harder to hide the *Search Index Manager*.  Enough that it is would be too frequent an operation and too much *mental memory* overhead, plus locating the file(s) in the index is something I would do too frequently to not automate the procedure.

I have gotten in the habit of archiving finished projects with `tar`. I use the `g` flag to `gzip` and `tar` the file in the same command.

*What is the official position on using a leading dash in `tar` arguments?* I've see it done three ways: *no leading dash*, *leading dash*, *leading dash with each argument used individually.*

### My Commands

```
tar cvfz "project.tgz" "project"`; mv "project" ~/.Trash
```

I `mv` the original files in ~/.Trash versus `rm`'ing them in case `tar` fails or I need to make last minute changes.

I have a script that finds all `.tgz` files(s) that are older than 2 weeks and `rm`'s them, as by that time I haven't touched them and feel it's safe to delete them. ( *I don't use "Empty Trash" as supplied by the OS but have selective file removal ( `rm` ) based on file *age* and *extension* )

I have a multi-level backup system. ( *On-site and remote* ) I don't waste tons of time in the *LaunchBar Index/Preferences* — the Index for *LaunchBar* changes frequently enough it's not feasible to manually exclude finished projects. *LaunchBar's* strength is it's ability to be extremely fast at adding and removing from the Index, all with a sub 3MB memory overhead.

### Question/Problem

When I unpack one of the `tar` archives, the results are **not as expected**. If a project lives at:
`/Users/me/Documents/Jobs/GitHub/In-Progress/Project-Name` And I create a `tar` file named "*cats.tgz*" which I unpack by double-clicking the file — OS X has a native Application that can unpack. `tar`, `gzip`, `zip`, and many others, while maintaining file meta-data, the end result is a directory called "*cats*".

Opening that directory I see `tar` has created an entire directory tree of **empty** directories back to the root drive. So "*cats*", once unpacked, has become a directory structure of:

```
/Volumes/drive-name/Users/me/Documents/Jobs/GitHub/In-Progress/Project-Name/cats/all-my-cats-files.
```

Each of the directories is empty aside from it's parent directory, which it would have to be or the `tar` command would spend a considerable amount of time packing up the "*me*", "*Documents*", and "*In-Progress*" directories.

It's as if there's was a:

```
mkdir -P /Volumes/drive-name/Users/me/Documents/Jobs/GitHub/In-Progress/Project-Name/cats
```

…command that was run prior to the `tar` command with the source pointing to the project name and the destination pointing to a long directory tree of empty directories.

I've *rarely* seen this in the thousands of `tar`, `tgz`, `zip`, and other compressed/combined archives I have unpacked over the years.

I could see this being handy in cases where you wanted to unpack an archive in a specific way to maintain a directory path structure — perhaps with files that were used within your project, some files and directories may need to be in specific locations.  For example: a call in your project code could find ~/bin/some-command, but the path would be wrong regardless as root ( / ) is now just a directory inside a directory inside my "*In-Progress*" directory.

### Conclusion and Closing Thoughts

Am I missing a flag? Is there a trailing slash that need or need not be in my `tar` command?

- This is one of very few adventures into MarkDown ( *.md* ), and for some reason… probably that i'm typing this on a mobile device, I don't see a preview of MarkDown -> rendered HTML display.

Stumped… any regular users of `tar` have any suggestions? My gut tells me not using the `gzip` command in one go may solve this. Instead make it a two part procedure of `tar` which when done calls `gzip` to finish the operation. I can't see it being `gzip` as that just takes one argument, the filename, and compresses it. There is a flag for *compression aggressiveness*, but I've always only stuck with the defaults.

Comment: the names usually exist in the tar themselves, and should generally all be in one directory to keep from tar-bombing your cd... you can check out the names without expanding if you use the `tar -tv` switches

Comment: @Scott- I can't help but feel you were a little verbose. Its usually best to state your problem and ask your question. I dread diatribes like this, and I just pass over them.

Comment: So, how exactly do you want to fix this? Do you want to know how to create archives that don't contain all these elements? Do you want to know how to suppress the leading directory elements on unpack? (This latter requires GNU extensions). Decide exactly what you want to know, and ask ONLY THAT QUESTION. Tersely. And in an appropriate forum ("how do I use this standard UNIX command?" is generally a better fit for SuperUser than StackOverflow).

Comment: Agreed with jww. This should be made far shorter before we can be expected to read it. It's not that we're lazy; look at similar questions and see how they made the point in about 1/4 of the space.

Answer (score 1):

**Mac OS X and GNU tar:**

Remove leading directory levels (with its content) while extracting/unpacking:

```
tar --strip-components=10 -xvzf "project.tgz"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, you need to `cd` into the directory the directory is that you want to `tar` up, then it will just be a single directory that when unpacked, will have only what you want, so:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    dirname=`dirname "$1"`
    filename=`basename "$1"`

    cd "$dirname"
    tar -czf "$filename".tar.gz "$filename"

    echo $dirname/$filename.tar.gz
fi
```

`cd "$dirname"` is important